# Seeing if estimators are unbiased

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

I have the pdf

$$f(y ; \theta) = \frac{1}{\theta} \exp( \frac{-y}{\theta}), \ y > 0$$

and I'm supposed to determine if the following two estimators are unbiased or not:  $ \hat \theta = nY_{min} $ and $ \hat \theta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i $.  I'm running into some problems because when I try to find the expected value of $ Y_{min} $ and $ Y_i $, the integral is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) and it shows that both the integral exist. Also, if you look lower in the article, you will also see that both the estimators are unbiased.

$Y_{min}$ is also exponentially distributed with mean parameter $\frac {\theta} {n}$

Therefore, $E[nY_{min}]=n\times\frac {\theta} {n} = \theta$. Similarly, $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i] = \frac{n \theta}{n}=\theta$

*I am sure both the integrals exists*

Comment: Ya, realized what I was doing.  Missed that whole exponential thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator is obtained combining these two facts:
1. The sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the population mean
2. The population mean is equal to theta